Download file from TeamCity with SSO using bash
I need to download an artefact from TC using a bash script (it should work in Ubuntu 22.04.3 deb based server). TeamCity authentication mode is SSO only via MS account and 2FA authentication. Is it possible somehow to write a bash script to download my TC builds?

I suggest applying security upgrades asap, as your details show you behind on applying security fixes. This link (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) will show the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded BEFORE that date to show 22.04.4

@guiverc it's a deb based 22.04.3 Ubuntu Server, not Core

My question answered on SO. Option #2 works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78590066/download-file-from-teamcity-with-sso-using-bash
